# Getting smart contract events (web3j)

Tags: java, events, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3-java

Please check/provide contract events example with web3j.

I got stuck several days, for what should be straightforward: Getting smart contract events

```java
    /**
     * Using Web3j .ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe()
     * that is sending eth_newFilter and eth_getfilterlogs/eth_getFilterChanges JSON RPC requests,
     * see https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_newfilter
     * and https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getfilterlogs ,
     * https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getfilterchanges
     * @param contractAddress
     */
    private void subscribeLogs(String contractAddress) {
        log.info("subscribeLogs({}) begin...", contractAddress);
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter( // fromBlock, toBlock, contractAddress
                //DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddress);
                DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddress);

        Disposable subscription = web3j
                .ethLogFlowable(filter)
                .subscribe(
                        logCounter
                        , errorCounter
                        , counterAction
                );
        subscriptions.add(subscription);
        log.info("subscribeLogs() end.");
    }
```

I was trying lambda and class like below for subscribe() Consumer parameter.
With counter like below, I am more sure I have not missed event in output.

```java
    int logCount = 0;
    // org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Log
    /**
     * Log object used by {@link org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthLog}
     * and {@link org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthGetTransactionReceipt}.
     */
    class LogCounter implements Consumer<Log>{
        @Override
        public void accept(Log logObject) throws Exception {
            logCount++;
            log.info("log #{} {}", logCount, logObject);
        }
    }
    LogCounter logCounter = new LogCounter();
```

The problem is that I can get no events at all.
(While similar code for blocks and transactions just work, events for a smart contract are just silent.
Of course I check contract address I am interesting, and send transaction)

Using

> DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddress);
> just gives NPE over JSON RPC error {"code":-32000,"message":"exceed maximum block range: 5000"}}  #1486
> So I only do latest blocks.
> I still wonder how to rescan older block events.

I am not using topic for filter hoping to see all
but was also trying this

````
Event targetEventTopic = new Event("Withdraw", Arrays.asList(
                
                new TypeReference<Address>() {},
                new TypeReference<Uint256>() {},
                new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}
        ));
        filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(targetEventTopic));
        ```
````